# SharePoint memory leak

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, memory-leaks, dispose

Does this contain a memory leak? I've been trying to better understand memory leaks, but I can't tell if I have corrected this? If not, how do I correctly dispose of the `SPweb` object and `SPSite` object?

```
using (SPWeb oWebsite = new SPSite(webUrl).OpenWeb()) //Open SP Web
{
    SPListCollection collList = oWebsite.Lists; //Open Lists

    foreach (SPList oList in collList)
    //For Each List Execute this
    {
        if (!oList.Hidden)
        //If the list is hidden do this else nothing
        {
            ListSitesDropDownBox.Items.Add(new ListItem(SPEncode.HtmlEncode(oList.Title), SPEncode.HtmlEncode(oList.Title)));
            ViewState["Item" + counter] = SPEncode.HtmlEncode(oList.Title);
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yep, it does. You dispose of `SPWeb` but forget disposing of `SPSite`.
The right way to do this:

```
using (var site = new SPSite(webUrl))
using (var web = site.OpenWeb()) {
    // ...
}
```

Note that this is equivalent to:

```
using (var site = new SPSite(webUrl)) {
    using (var web = site.OpenWeb()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

but I omitted braces for outer `using` to reduce code nesting. The bracing rules are the same as for `if`.

A few stylistic remarks:

- Please, [don't use Systems Hungarian in C# code](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html). Just `list`.
- Comments that rephrase the code above don't make any sense. Keep them constructive, i.e. explaining the purpose of the code. Instead of those four comments, you should've written something like that in the beginning:

  ```
  // Populate drop-down list with list names and save them in ViewState
  ```

Comment: +1. This is the article you need to read if you work with SPxxx objects - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248.aspx

Comment: what are you referring to when you say just List?

Comment: You use Hungarian notation for naming variables, i.e. prefix your variable names with type name abbreviations. I understand `o` stands for `object`. However this is absolutely unnecessary in C# because it has strong type system and VS is a powerful IDE with features like IntelliSense. I advise you to use `website` instead of `oWebsite`, `list` instead of `oList`, `lists` (or `allLists`) instead of clumsy `collList` et cetera.

Comment: @atrljoe Have a read at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation - I still whack out code in Hungarian knowing that it's unneccesary these days but it's really out of habit. New coders probably use it still too from reading lots of code samples that do use it, and think it's normal, when infact, it's quite archaic practice in C#.

Comment: +1 This is an excellent answer. I love how you go into a) the answer to the question, b) show some useful syntactic sugar with 'using', and c) talk about coding style. All in like, 15 lines of text! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You are not disposing SPSite object in your using, only SPWeb.

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered your question, but I'll add that you should be running your builds through SPDisposeCheck: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SPDisposeCheck

It isn't perfect but it will tip you off early to a lot of problems.